# How do I enable full text search on MySql 8?

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, full-text-search, mysql-8.0

I'm using MySql 8.  I would like to speed up searches on my table of the form

```
select * FROM dirctory_coop where name like '%mystr%';
```

and someone mentioned using Full text searches -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html.  However, I'm having an issue with this.  Below is my table ...

```
mysql> desc directory_coop;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name     | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enabled  | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phone_id | int          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| email_id | int          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| web_site | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I tried the below statements to update my column definition but am getting the following errors ...

```
mysql> alter table directory_coop modify column name FULLTEXT;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULLTEXT' at line 1
mysql> alter table directory_coop modify name FULLTEXT;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FULLTEXT' at line 1
```

What else do I need to do to enable the performance optimizations that full text search supposedly provides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add or create an INDEx like

```
 ALTER TABLE directory_coop ADD FULLTEXT idx_name(name);
```

For more information read the manual [ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you must do is to create a `FULLTEXT` index as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE directory_coop ADD FULLTEXT name_ftndx (name);
```

That's just the beginning.

The next thing you need to do is understand the SQL syntax for using `FULLTEXT` indexes.

**Please read the [MySQL Documentation on FULLTEXT Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)**

I have [many posts in the DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A877%20FULLTEXT) about using them.

Here is a good example to start you off : [Why full-text-search returns less rows than LIKE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21118/why-full-text-search-returns-less-rows-than-like/21128#21128). This will show you the difference between using LIKE and using the MATCH function.

[I still recommend reading the MySQL Docs before reading my posts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html).

## CAVEAT

Please know that [36 Words are not included in an InnoDB FULLTEXT Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-stopwords.html#fulltext-stopwords-stopwords-for-innodb-search-indexes).

I have mentioned the twice in the DBA StackExchange

- `Aug 05, 2019` : [Get stopwords of a InnoDB fulltext index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/244562/get-stopwords-of-a-innodb-fulltext-index/244605#244605)
- `May 05, 2018` : [Mysql Fulltext search doesn't return any results](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205903/mysql-fulltext-search-doesnt-return-any-results/205905#205905)